# Netdiscover not identifying devices

Tags: mac, ip, netdiscover

When I use `netdiscover` it only shows VMWare MAC vendors, it doesn't show the devices connected to my WiFi.

I tried many codes like `netdiscover -r thr ip` but it doesn't identify the devices, it only says VMWare inc., no real company names like Apple or Samsung.

Is it because I'm not connected successfully to the WiFi or what?

Comment: Please proofread before posting next time. Now, regarding your question, it seems you need to understand what a virtual machine is, how hardware is virtualized and how networking works inside the VM, before anything else.